# How to automatically indent #pragma directive in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone have any idea on how to ensure that `#pragma` directives in Visual Studio 2013 (C++ project) are indented properly?

I'm annoyed by the fact that Visual Studio always eliminates the indentation I made to these directives. It makes it difficult to collapse sections of my source code. The example below is an example of no indentation. If it was indented, then it would be easier to read.

```
void func()
{
#pragma region section 1
#pragma endregion
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that no `#pragma` expression should be indented to show, that they are scopeless. Because in this special question `#pragma region MyName` is nothing, that will change the code path or any meaning of it. Region pragmas are only meta information for the IDE. I am feeling tempted to say, that Microsoft mis-uses the `#pragma`keyword to enable the IDE feature that regions can be collapsed.

In my daily codebase preprocessor directives are scarce, but there are many `region` directives. Therefore I do not risk to misinterprete the text by indenting pragmas.
If you like to indent `#pragma` expressions, you can enable it under:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Indentation > Position of preprocessor directives > Leave indented`

This works at least since Visual Studio 2017 with *Productivity Power Tools* installed.

Comment: I use `region` frequently to hide unimportant code parts all the time. It looks really great with indentation. +1

Answer (score 4):

If it were indented, then it would be misleading. `#pragma`s are *preprocessor directives*, and do not abide by scope. You are attempting to tell readers of your code the opposite.

Visual Studio is being sensible, for once, and I don't know how to change that behaviour.

Comment: Or alternatively, you know full well that they're scopeless and you don't want your code to look fugly with a bunch of unindented stuff strewn about.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400690/4342498) by [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit).  Preprocessor commands are are acted on regardless of there indentation and having them with 0 indentations helps to call out the the block of code is wrapped by them.

That said if you want to stop MSVS from changing the indentation you can go to

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs
```

And change it from Smart to Block.  This will stop auto indentation from happening on everything else as well so you might not want it.